# Windows EC2 instances do not come with AWS CLI?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I am using auto-scale to create a large number of windows based instances. I created an elastic IP and logged in to one of these instances. My user-data script depend on the awscli, which doesn't come by default in the chosen "free tier" instances. 
Is there a common solution to this issue ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A couple of options:

1. Update your scripts to use the AWS Tools for PowerShell on Windows. Vanilla Windows AMIs on Amazon come installed with the [AWS Tools For PowerShell](https://aws.amazon.com/powershell/), rather than the CLI.
2. Download and install the AWS CLI as a part of your user-data scripts.

### Further Reading

- [AWS Documentation - Install the AWS Command Line Interface on Microsoft Windows](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/awscli-install-windows.html#awscli-install-windows-pip)

Answer (score 4):

*Windows PowerShell for AWS* is installed on Windows EC2 instances.

Using this guide you can essentially run commands using PowerShell to achieve the same thing as the AWS CLI: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/powershell/latest/reference/Index.html

For example, to download a zip file from S3, open *Windows PowerShell for AWS* from the Start menu and run:

```
Copy-S3Object -BucketName "my-bucket" -Key "path/to/file.zip" -LocalFile "C:\Users\my-user\Downloads\file.zip"
```